# Implementing Tab bar ctrl in dashcode

Tags: iphone, dashcode

I am developing web application for iphone. Is it possible to implement Tab bar controller in dashcode.

Is there is any option available for implementing tab bar using dashcode for developing web application.

Thanks
mindus

Answer (score 0):

you probably could do it in dashcode but there are no library items that let you do it out of the box as it were. i think also that the limited real estate when Dashcode is targeting iPhone apps is such that you probably would not use tabs as a standard method of navigation and this may be the reason for it's absence. However if doing browsers and possibly iPad (which does not seem to be catered for in Dashcode at all) then this wouldn't be the case.

Quickly looking at Sencha Touch and Sproutcore touch i cannot see any tabbed paradigms. Which again is i suspect due to the nature of the Touch method of navigating where the vertical table view tend to be the norm.

To do it in dash code would be simple enough as you could simply use JavaScript + css to implement the tabs.